Error proyecto Formly-Form angular v17
Estoy intentando levantar un proyecto ejemplo con formly, es un proyecto standalone, y tengo una serie de errores que no se muy como solucionar, es como si no detectará el formly-form.
Así tengo el component.ts
  standalone: true,
   imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterOutlet,
    CommonModule,   
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormlyBootstrapModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatMenuModule]
  ,
  providers: [
    HttpClientModule,

  ],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})


Y en el module tengo esto
  imports: [
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormlyModule.forRoot({
      validationMessages: [
        { name: 'required', message: 'This field is required' },
        { name: 'type', message: typeValidationMessage },
        { name: 'minLength', message: minLengthValidationMessage },
        { name: 'maxLength', message: maxLengthValidationMessage },
        { name: 'min', message: minValidationMessage },
        { name: 'max', message: maxValidationMessage },
        { name: 'multipleOf', message: multipleOfValidationMessage },
        { name: 'exclusiveMinimum', message: exclusiveMinimumValidationMessage },
        { name: 'exclusiveMaximum', message: exclusiveMaximumValidationMessage },
        { name: 'minItems', message: minItemsValidationMessage },
        { name: 'maxItems', message: maxItemsValidationMessage },
        { name: 'uniqueItems', message: 'should NOT have duplicate items' },
        { name: 'const', message: constValidationMessage },
        { name: 'enum', message: `must be equal to one of the allowed values` },
      ],
      types: [
        { name: 'null', component: NullTypeComponent, wrappers: ['form-field'] },
        { name: 'array', component: ArrayTypeComponent },
        { name: 'object', component: ObjectTypeComponent },
        { name: 'multischema', component: MultiSchemaTypeComponent },
      ],
    }),
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  declarations: [AppComponent, ArrayTypeComponent, ObjectTypeComponent, MultiSchemaTypeComponent, NullTypeComponent],
})
export class AppModule {} ```

<br>

Porque no me deja poner el FormlyModule.forRoot en el component.ts


¿Cuál es el error?

Me dice 'formly-form' is not a know element: Add to @Component.imports
